# Page Size In WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

If the `WebBrowser` in xaml is for example 50px wide, the webpage thinks the browser is actually 480px
I tested this using `http://whatsmybrowsersize.com/` on the phone, no matter the size of the `WebBrowser`, the page always thinks its 480, in effect this reduces the size of everything to fit in the 50px, is there a way to alter this, so the window 50px but the content doesn't get reduced to fit

the best way to explain this it think would be, make an a circle with your finger and thumb and put it over the stack overflow logo on your screen, all you see is the icon, that is what I'm after but the `WebBrowser` is squashing the entire page into that circle

Thanks

Comment: Can you modify the WebView content? (e.g. can you change the Html?) You can change most of the WebView behaviors via Css, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453816.aspx

Comment: No i dont have access to the html

Comment: Ok, you can use NavigateToString, load the content manually and inject the CSS.